# Knitr not producing what i am expecting if I cut and paste the code in R terminal

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

If I `knit` the following piece of code:

````
```{r, eval=TRUE}
times <- function(total = 3, name="a") {
    ctr <- 1
    function(expr, val, ok, visible) {
        cat("[Task ", name, "] ", ctr,"\n", sep="")
        ctr <<- ctr + 1
        return(ctr <= total)
    }
}

h <- taskCallbackManager()
h$suspend()
h$add(times())
h$add(times(4,"b"))
h$add(times(5,"c"))
h$add(times(6,"d"))
h$suspend(FALSE)
```
````

I don't any output after last command `(h$suspend(FALSE))`. However, if I cut and paste the code into R, I get the following output:

```
[Task a] 1
[Task b] 1
[Task c] 1
[Task d] 1
```

Any reason why this might be the case?

Comment: This looks complicated. My guess is, the callbacks are executed _after_ the code has been evaluated, and evaluate (on which knitr depends) will not be able to capture the output; anyone interested in this issue is very welcome to submit a patch to https://github.com/hadley/evaluate thanks! (relevant pieces are in eval.r and watcher.r)

Comment: The follow-up discussion is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knitr/rrcJfcm0sbI), and now I do not think it is possible to solve this problem, but I'll be happy to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and this maybe wasn't possible then, but today you can intercept one of `knitr`'s hooks:

```
knit_hooks$set(evaluate = function(...) {
  res  <- evaluate::evaluate(...)

  # instead of recordPlot()
  plot <- Filter(evaluate::is.recordedplot, res)
  plot <- if (length(plot)) plot[[1]]

  # expression and equivalent of the globalenv()
  args  <- list(...)
  env   <- args$envir
  expr  <- parse(text = paste(args[[1]], collapse = '\n'))

  # here call your actual callback

  # return the value that knitr expects
  res
})
```